# Display Flash Debug Log to a console

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, debugging

I am debugging my flash application, what is the best way to read the trace log from a non browser ? I want to be able to read in a C# application.

Any suggestions ?

Regards

Comment: You want to display the trace log in a C# application? How are you running your flash application? Are your running it in AIR? On what type of device?

Comment: It is a browser flash app

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Scout, Flash, and Monster Debugger call all report debug information from a flash app running in a browser and provide excellent debugging features. The flash debug player sends logging info to a flashlog.txt which you could read with a C# app if that's really what you wanted to do.

There's also the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class.